# Using crontab from php

Tags: php, cron

I am having troubles with setting up a server which would allow me to manage cron jobs from PHP scripts.
The idea is: users can create as many tasks as they want with possibility to set alarm(s) for each. After alarm is saved into MySQL database, I want to create a cronjob for that entry on user specified time.

The logic is pretty simple but I am getting frustrated over unix user/file permissions. The problem is, user "www-data" has no permissions to run crontab, thus I cannot use it to manage cronjobs via shell_exec invocation in php scripts. I have read a lot of tutorial/threads on similar issues but without any luck. The closest I could get was that I should make sure www-data user has permissions to run crontab (which I am pretty positive it does not have). However, I put "www-data" user into "crontab" group, I created "cron.allow" file in "/etc/cron.d" directory, but still nothing.

Btw, I am using $output = shell_exec("crontab -u www-data -l") to see if it's working or not (if $output == null then there was an error).

What should I do to make this working? Or should I use a bit different approach (maybe I could have some file writeable by www-data and set somewhere in crontab configuration that it should check for cronjobs in there as well, but I dont know how to do that neither)?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You could put a modified file into `/etc/cron.d` which is also read for cron comamnds.

Disclaimer: I've not done this (though I'll be damned if I can remember how I did this last time at all)

Comment: I cannot find anything on "include" on Google tho, just basic `crontab -e/-l/-r` and `crontab /path/to/file`. In short, I want crontab to check another file which will be accessible/editable via php scripts, not to replace all cron jobs with that file. If you meant executing crontab without any argument and then type `include /location/to/file` I don't know how to save it (can close it only with CTRL+C, which terminates process without saving anything). The best would be specifiyng that file in some way in main cron file (in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directory).

Comment: I do apologise, I could swear I had done it, but perhaps I'm getting confused with a shell script or something. I've amended my answer as it's incorrect and all.

Comment: no problem, as I see it such functionality would be incredibly useful, at least I can see how it would make certain scheduling jobs much easier than they are right now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that system my app is running on is handling cron.allow/cron.deny files very oddly (at least to my understanding of these files). I deleted `/etc/cron.allow` file and suddenly www-data user can use crontab command in php scripts. I have no idea why it didn't work with having www-data user stated in cron.allow file, but it looks like it works now.